# How to make LabelFormatter only effect one bindling value by using LiveChart Gauge

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, livecharts

I am using LiveChart Gauge to make a dashboard program. I want to display the value with `%` symbol, but it also change my Max value.

How can i only effect 1 binding value instead all binding value?

**XAML**

```
<lvc:Gauge Grid.Row="2" 
           Grid.Column="0" 
           Margin="15" 
           Foreground="White" 
           GaugeActiveFill="Yellow"
           From="0"
           To="{Binding totalTargetQuantity}"
           Value="{Binding ChartValue2}"
           LabelFormatter="{Binding Formatter2}"/>
```

**Before use labelformatter**

[image: Before use labelformatter]

**After use labelformatter**

[image: After use labelformatter]

**Result that i need**

[image: Result that i need]

Can anyone help me on this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same answer as Alexandr with modifications:
Download and open [LiveCharts.Wpf.dll](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LiveCharts.Wpf/) with **dnspy** and find line:
`this.MeasureTextBlock.Text = (this.LabelFormatter ?? func)(this.Value);`

Click Edit Method and replace that line by:
`this.MeasureTextBlock.Text = "% " + (this.LabelFormatter ?? func)(this.Value);`
Now Click Compile.
 
File -> Save Module -> LiveCharts.Wpf.dll
Now this dll will show gauge like:
 [image]

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there is no way to do this "out of box". So every solution will be "special", it may even seem like a crutch.

Not sure in which order I should put them.

1. Make original Gauge labels hidden and create special UserControl/Adorner to overlay them with Text you like
2. Download source codes of LiveCharts, find Gauge.cs in "WpfView" solution. Find private
   Update() method.
   You are looking for next lines:

   ```
   LeftLabel.Text = (LabelFormatter ?? defFormatter)(From);
   RightLabel.Text = (LabelFormatter ?? defFormatter)(To);
   ```

   Clone gauge, or introduce separate LabelFormatter for each Label there.

Cannot think of something else. Either you "fake" original labels, either you change sources, because there is no way to override this behavior.

Comment: Thank you! But I think this way is a little difficult for me, I will try if i can edit the code inside WpfView and make it work later.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't as the LiveCharts Gauge doesn't provide option to format the labels separately. what you could do is to hide the bottom labels and provide your own, tho you would have to position it manually, eg:

```
 <Grid>
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition />
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <lvc:Gauge
         x:Name="myGauge"
         Margin="15,35"
         LabelFormatter="{Binding Formatter2}"
         LabelsVisibility="Collapsed"
         StrokeThickness="2"
         Value="9"
         From="0"
         To="10"
         />
     <Label Content="{Binding ElementName=myGauge, Path=From}" FontSize="20" Margin="100,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
     <Label Content="{Binding ElementName=myGauge, Path=To}" FontSize="20" Margin="100,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
 </Grid>
```

[image]

EDIT:
Or add the labels in ControlTemplate:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="GaugeStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type lvc:Gauge}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type lvc:Gauge}">
                        <Border
                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <Grid>
                                <ContentPresenter
                                    HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                    VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                    Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                    ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}"
                                    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                                <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Label
                                        Grid.Row="2"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                        Content="{Binding ElementName=myGauge, Path=From}"
                                        FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" />
                                    <Label
                                        Grid.Row="2"
                                        Grid.Column="2"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                        Content="{Binding ElementName=myGauge, Path=To}"
                                        FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" />
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <lvc:Gauge
            x:Name="myGauge"
            Margin="15"
            FontSize="30"
            LabelFormatter="{Binding Formatter2}"
            LabelsVisibility="Collapsed"
            StrokeThickness="2"
            Style="{DynamicResource GaugeStyle1}"
            Value="9"
            From="0"
            To="10" />
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks! This way is much easier for me. 
I have add 2 label on the bottom to cover original position.